# Azure AD Configurable Token Lifetimes not being Applied

Tags: access-token, azure-active-directory

I want to change the default token lifetimes in Azure AD [as shown here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-configurable-token-lifetimes), but it looks like the changes are not being applied.

I am running the following commands using the PowerShell cmdlets in the [AzureAdPreview module from the PowerShell Gallery](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/AzureADPreview/2.0.0.50):

```
New-AzureADPolicy -Definition @("{`"TokenLifetimePolicy`":{`"Version`":1, `"AccessTokenLifetime`":`"10:00`",`"MaxInactiveTime`":`"10:00`",`"MaxAgeSingleFactor`":`"10:00`",`"MaxAgeMultiFactor`":`"10:00`",`"MaxAgeSessionSingleFactor`":`"10:00`",`"MaxAgeSessionMultiFactor`":`"10:00`"}}") -DisplayName AbsoluteMinimumPolicyScenario -IsOrganizationDefault $false -Type TokenLifetimePolicy
```

I want to set all token lifetimes to the bare-minimum 10 minutes in order to test some auth code in my web API.

I then assign this policy to my registered application in Azure AD:

```
Add-AzureADApplicationPolicy -ObjectId <application-object-id> -RefObjectId <policy-id>
```

Using `Get-AzureADPolicyAppliedObject -ObjectId <policy-id>` I confirm that my policy has been applied to my application...

... and yet, when I attempt to retrieve a fresh access token during login (using ADAL), I can see that the expiry date is still at the default of 1 hour.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Were you assigning the policy to the resource you were requesting tokens?  For instance, if I built an Android app that needed access to the Microsoft Graph, you would need to set the policy on the Microsoft Graph service principal.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to follow the format for time parameter set for 10 minutes as below.

```
00:10:00
```

Besides, in my lab, I find that the policy only can work when the parameter **IsOrganizationDefault** is set as **$true**. The policy can't be enforced even though it's explicitly assigned to the specific application or service principle.

Comment: Setting `IsOrganizationDefault` to `$true` is what got this working - but it affects other applications in the organization which is a big no-no. Seems to me that this a bug in Azure AD; any idea when this will be fixed?

Comment: @SameerSingh, what Andy said isn't accurate.  You can set a policy on a service principal or an application just fine.  It's important to mention, the policy must be set on the resource you're requesting tokens to as this dictates the token lifetime.

Comment: @DanielDobalian I just realized that there are two Object Ids for my application in Azure: one in Azure Active Directory -> **Enterprise applications** -> All applications -> {My Application} -> Properties and another in Azure Active Directory -> **App registrations** -> {My Application} -> Properties. Which one is it? Will do some quick testing now.

Comment: @DanielDobalian Tests show that I should be using the Object Id in the App registrations view because the other one throws an error. However, if I set `IsOrganizationDefault` to `$false` and assign the policy to this Object Id, the policy has no effect. I still get access tokens that expire in 1 hour instead of 10 minutes.

Comment: @SameerSingh is the app your linking the policy the resource server that's being requested?  See my comment on your original question for reference.  For explanation of [oAuth2.0 roles](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6749#section-1.1).

Comment: @DanielDobalian I believe I am: the application is registered in Azure AD (the authorization server) and requires permissions to the O365 Exchange API and the Azure AD API (the resources). In this I am thinking that I request an access token for the application from Azure AD in order to use the O365 API, so this is why I apply the policy to the application. If this is incorrect, where would I look in the Azure Portal for the Object Ids of the O365 API and the Azure AD API in order to apply the policy to them?

Comment: You would want to set the policy on the service principal of the API. To checkout the service principals in your tenant, you can use the [graph explorer](https://graphexplorer.cloudapp.net/).  Sign in to your Azure AD account, then append /servicePrincipals, and search.

Comment: @DanielDobalian Thanks for that; however I do not see "Office 365 Exchange Online (Microsoft.Exchange)" in the Graph Explorer. This is quite puzzling.

Comment: @DanielDobalian I hope you can appreciate the difficulties associated with using overloaded terms such as "application" and "service principal" in [Configurable Token Lifetimes in Azure Active Directory](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-configurable-token-lifetimes). It is unclear which application or service principal the examples are referring to; it is easy to assume "application" refers to my application registered on Azure AD. There is no indication that I would instead need to apply the policy to the APIs that my application is required to access.

Comment: @SameerSingh totally valid. I'll update the doc to provide more clarity on the issue you ran into and a more finite sample.

Comment: @DanielDobalian how are the updates to the docs going? I see the published version hasn't changed but there have been lots of updates in the Github repo. I am waiting for the docs to be updated and for the feature to become GA before I attempt this again.

Comment: I haven't forgotten! We're working on getting the underlying feature GA at which point there will be a refactor of the docs surrounding it. Unfortunately, I can't give a time estimate on GA at this time. I made an update a few months ago to at least mention your feedback in the `Configurable policy property details` section, but probably need to mention this in a couple more places.

Answer (score 0):

I made it work by only using `New-AzureADPolicy` cmdlet and setting `-IsOrganizationDefault $true` not `$false`. The effect takes a while for you to see it. So wait for about 30 minutes to an hour (I don't know how long exactly). After that your new policy will be created and applied. Also remember that this is PowerShell, so no whitespaces in the cmdlet.

Example:

```
New-AzureADPolicy -Definition @('{"TokenLifetimePolicy":{"Version":1,"AccessTokenLifetime":"02:00:00","MaxInactiveTime":"02:00:00","MaxAgeSessionSingleFactor":"02:00:00"}}') -DisplayName "PolicyScenario" -IsOrganizationDefault $true -Type "TokenLifetimePolicy"
```

Multi-Line version:

```
New-AzureADPolicy -Definition @(
    '
        {
            "TokenLifetimePolicy":
                {
                    "Version": 1,
                    "AccessTokenLifetime": "02:00:00",
                    "MaxInactiveTime": "02:00:00",
                    "MaxAgeSessionSingleFactor": "02:00:00"
                }
        }
    '
    ) -DisplayName "PolicyScenario" -IsOrganizationDefault $true -Type "TokenLifetimePolicy"
```

Microsoft may fix the issue with `IsOrganizationDefault $true`. Read more on this in the question: [Azure AD Configurable Token Lifetimes not being Applied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41799280/azure-ad-configurable-token-lifetimes-not-being-applied/44231959#44231959).

Comment: As detailed in the other answer it works if you use the `-IsOrganizationDefault` parameter and set it to `$true`. The downside is that, with this parameter, it's a global setting rather than an application setting. In addition this answer is also posted on [Configurable token lifetimes in Azure Active Directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44205464/configurable-token-lifetimes-in-azure-active-directory/44231982#44231982). Just including it as a reference.