# Configurable token lifetimes in Azure Active Directory

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-graph-api

I could not assign  `TokenLifetimePolicy` Azure AD application policy from PowerShell. I had an error `BadRequest` : `Message: Open navigation properties are not supported on OpenTypes.Property name: 'policies`

I am trying to implement token expiry time from [Configurable token lifetimes in Azure Active Directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-configurable-token-lifetimes#configurable-token-lifetime-properties)

See screenshot below, any useful links and solutions on the AzureAD cmdlet `Add-AzureADApplicationPolicy` are welcome

[image]

Comment: Why a screenshot if the text would be better readable and probably save space? in addition the command is cut off. As it is your command might be incorrect.

Comment: I would double check the Object ID's you're using in the command is correct.  For the app, go to the [Azure Portal](https://portal.azure.com) and for the policy you can use `Get-AzureADPolicy`.

Comment: @Seth How has your comments answered this question. Thought we only post questions or answers here. A picture is worth a thousand words, and the command accepts only two arguments,`Id` and `RefObjectId` which have both been passed

Comment: A comment isn't there to answer a question but to ask for more information and clarification. In addition we're dealing with code. If your screenshot would show a UI glitch or similar, I'd understand that you'd post it. But your question is about code and in addition it's incomplete. Granted, in this case that might be OK but usually its a good idea to include the code in text and as a whole. Your answer also shows that. What use would it be if it was cut-off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made it work by only using `New-AzureADPolicy` cmdlet and setting `-IsOrganizationDefault $true` not `$false`. The effect takes a while for you to see it. So wait for about 30 minutes to an hour (I don't know how long exactly). After that your new policy will be created and applied. Also remember that this is PowerShell, so no whitespaces in the cmdlet.

Example:

```
New-AzureADPolicy -Definition @('{"TokenLifetimePolicy":{"Version":1,"AccessTokenLifetime":"02:00:00","MaxInactiveTime":"02:00:00","MaxAgeSessionSingleFactor":"02:00:00"}}') -DisplayName "PolicyScenario" -IsOrganizationDefault $true -Type "TokenLifetimePolicy"
```

Multi-Line version:

```
New-AzureADPolicy -Definition @(
    '
        {
            "TokenLifetimePolicy":
                {
                    "Version": 1,
                    "AccessTokenLifetime": "02:00:00",
                    "MaxInactiveTime": "02:00:00",
                    "MaxAgeSessionSingleFactor": "02:00:00"
                }
        }
    '
    ) -DisplayName "PolicyScenario" -IsOrganizationDefault $true -Type "TokenLifetimePolicy"
```

Microsoft may fix the issue with `IsOrganizationDefault $true`. Read more on this in the question: [Azure AD Configurable Token Lifetimes not being Applied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41799280/azure-ad-configurable-token-lifetimes-not-being-applied/44231959#44231959).

Answer (score 1):

I test this quite a bit for my customers. I run into issues like this every now and then due to not on the latest version of PowerShell.

```
get-module
```

Latest Version 2.0.0.114 at the moment for AzureADPreview (V2)
[Instructions to download here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/install-adv2?view=azureadps-2.0)

There was an issue with -IsOrganizationDefault $true as Seth has pointed out.

Another issue I've found is having multiple versions of PowerShell on your system and it's loading the wrong one that doesn't have the updated bits.  I hit this last Friday - I had to wipe everything and reinstall - then it fixed it.

Also -

There is a difference between:

```
Add-AzureADApplicationPolicy
```

and

```
Add-AzureADServicePrincipalPolicy
```

One is for an application object and the other is for a ServicePrincipal. If you are applying it to say, a SAML-Based application, then you should apply it to the ServicePrincpal.

**Note:** There is a different ObjectID for the application object and the servicePrincipal object. Don't get these confused.  For an experiment, run the two cmds against your application:

```
Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -SearchString <name of app>
Get-AzureADApplication -SearchString <name of app>
```

If you grab the wrong ObjectID - no go when you go to apply the policy

The sequence for these Policies are:  ServicePrincipal -> Application -> Tenant (organization)

Answer (score 0):

Was the application created in B2C portal?

Assuming the answer is yes, this behavior is expected:
Microsoft has 2 authorization end points, V1 and V2.

B2C portal creates V2 apps. The token lifetime setting from powershell probably only works against the V1 apps.

There are settings on the b2c blade to change this.

The other option is to create an app from the azure active directory blade(as opposed to the b2c blade). Then you can set the token life time using powershell.